# Dependency hell in cabal. It is really a hell

Tags: haskell, cabal

Different programming languages use different packaging systems.

In their varied approach, Java's `Maven` looks like the best bet for me since it maintains different version of jar files in seperately versioned folders and hence, there is no way one will end up in conflicting versions of a library.

Next comes python. Python's `pip` puts its packages into `/usr/local/lib/python/dist-packages/site-packages`. When there is a version conflict, one can use its `virtualenv` and live with it.

Nodejs supports installing packages both in local folders and global folders. Till date for me, i never had a dependency conflict in the global libraries.

Then I got fascinated by the haskell's style and started using `cabal`. First, i was installing my libraries inside `/home/user1/.cabal`. Then when the package system broke, one friend suggested me to remove two folders - `/home/user1/.cabal && /home/user1/.ghc`. Now, my first confusion arose, why does cabal's library files sit in two folders `.cabal && .ghc`. I cleaned the library folders, `~/.ghc and ~/.cabal` and did `cabal install` from a package source for `cabal-db-0.1.12`.  Now, there was a new error and i was surprised, because i had sanitized all local repositories. The error was,

```
Configuring Cabal-1.22.2.0...
Building Cabal-1.22.2.0...
Installed Cabal-1.22.2.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
ansi-terminal-0.6.2.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
user error (The package 'ansi-terminal' requires Cabal library version -any &&
>=1.6 but no suitable version is installed.)
```

Then I tried the safest bet - `sandbox` for `cabal-db`. It worked. Then i repeated sandboxing for another pacakge, ghc-pkg-autofix. I did,

```
cd ghc-pkg-autofix-0.2.0.1
cabal sandbox init
cabal install
```

And for sandbox where there are absolutely no external dependencies,  there are errors again,

```
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: ghc-pkg-autofix-0.2.0.1 (user goal)
trying: Cabal-1.22.2.0 (dependency of ghc-pkg-autofix-0.2.0.1)
next goal: process (dependency of ghc-pkg-autofix-0.2.0.1)
rejecting: process-1.2.0.0/installed-06c..., 1.2.3.0, 1.2.2.0, 1.2.1.0,
1.2.0.0, 1.1.0.2, 1.1.0.1, 1.1.0.0 (conflict: ghc-pkg-autofix => process>=1.0
&& <1.1)
rejecting: process-1.0.1.5, 1.0.1.4, 1.0.1.3, 1.0.1.2, 1.0.1.1, 1.0.0.0
(conflict: Cabal => process>=1.1.0.1 && <1.3)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.

Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent
dependencies. Try reinstalling/unregistering the offending packages or
recreating the sandbox.
```

Am i doing something wrong (or) this kind of dependency conflicts are quite common in cabal? I see, managing dependencies in other languages are a lot simpler.

Note: I use `cabal-install version 1.22.0.0` && `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.4`

Comment: nope it's not common - but very common for beginners. Indeed the easiest way for beginners is IMHO to setup a clean environment and use sandboxes. There is [a nice tutorial on how to do it here](http://www.stackage.org/install) (you don't have to use the stackage parts if you don't want to - if you have GHC 7.10.1 you actually cannot AFAIK) - btw: did you use cabal-1.22 on purpose (i.e. with GHC 7.10.1?) because using Haskell plattform I would not right now)

Comment: btw: just curious - how does maven handle the situation where Package X depends on A-Vers1 and Y on a-Vers2 (not compatible) and you want to use both X and Y?

Comment: Inside `M2_HOME` repository, maven will create two folders like `A/1.0.0/*` and `A/2.0.0/*`. Since the global repository uses seperate folders based on versions, different versions of same `archetype/jar` can sit inside your system in one place.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar That's nice for the packages for just sitting there, but what if I want to actually use those libraries? Java doesn't allow you to load multiple classes of the same name into the VM at the same time, or when you can make it do that, you will get really weird exceptions when you use them.

Comment: @SebastianRedl exactly - the problem is still there you just get at it a bit later

Comment: As for your first error, what does `ghc-pkg list Cabal` say? I hope you didn't remove libraries from `/opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4`!

Comment: @ReidBarton, for God's sake don't even ask someone to remove lib files in /opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib. cabal marks package constraints for ghc's packages as `installed` in `.config` file. And you touch those libraries, all those `cabal install` will sincerely fail....

Comment: @CarstenKönig It will print out a warning, and IIRC use the version that appeared the earliest in the POM. Gradle allows you to handle this explicitly (by making one package have its dependencies override that of others, or by disabling transitive dependencies for specific packages etc), which is nice.

Comment: I didn't suggest that anyone should remove those libraries. But what you wrote could be interpreted as saying that you did so. In any case something seems to have been broken with your setup when you built cabal-db the first time, since you should have had Cabal installed already but apparently Cabal built itself again for some reason and then complained that it could not find Cabal.

Comment: @ReidBarton, thanks Reid. I removed the line about /opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib. thanks. i have cabal 1.22.0 in my system but the error still says `'ansi-terminal' requires Cabal library version -any &&
>=1.6 but no suitable version is installed`.. i am not sure, how this error arose since i am already using the latest version of cabal

Comment: @ReidBarton, thanks Reid. I removed the line about /opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib. thanks. i have cabal 1.22.0 in my system but the error still says `'ansi-terminal' requires Cabal library version -any &&
>=1.6 but no suitable version is installed`.. i see this line, `Cabal-Version:       >= 1.6` inside `ansi-terminal.cabal` but i am already using the latest cabal in my system.

Answer (score 5):

"And for sandbox where there are absolutely no external dependencies" this is not true. A sandbox still has dependencies on the global package database. Things like Cabal, GHC, process are typically installed in the global package database. Here you want to install ghc-pkg-autofix which requires process 1.0, but you have a more recent version of process already installed. Are you sure you need ghc-pkg-autofix, it seems to be quite old.

Comment: Not only does the OP have a more recent version of process installed, but ghc-pkg-autofix also depends on Cabal, and the OP's version of Cabal requires a more recent version of process than the one ghc-pkg-autofix (supposedly) requires, so this is a real diamond dependency problem.